# While in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, while-loop

Good morning to everyone here, I try to make a query of the following form with zend framework but I can not, I want to use while because with foreach already do, leave my code to see where I'm wrong:

Model.php

```
<?php

class Application_Model_Datas 
{



    public function listar()
    {
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();

$select = $db->select()
             ->from('album');

return $db->fetchAll($select);

    }
}
```

Index.phtml

```
<?php
//And your view looks like this.
while ($select = $this->datos){
   print_r($results);
}


?>
```

Controller.php

```
    <?php

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
                     $table = new Application_Model_Datas(); 

                     $this->view->datos = $table->listar();
    }


}
```

The problem is it does not show me any errors or data or anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has no sense/effect

```
<?php

//And your view looks like this.
while ($select = $this->datos){
   print_r($results); //Normally you get in an infinite loop
}

?>
```

You just need to iterate over a simple array :

```
$i = 0;

while($i < count($this->datos)) {
    print_r($this->datos[$i++]); //Getting current element, and incremeting counter
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much friend, is trying to do just that! Greetings!